# What is the best way to make music play more slowly? (at any arbitrary speed)

Tags: software, audio

And what is the best program to use for that?

Comment: Welcome to the site @InquilineKea!  I think you'll get quicker and better answers if you break this up into two separate questions.

Comment: I have edited to remove your second question from this post.  Please feel free to ask it in a separate question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Speed (Pitch) and Tempo are two different things. If you are looking for simple pitch change, then the apps that TheLQ mentioned would suffice.

However, if you are looking to timestretch the music, that is change it's tempo without affecting its pitch, then you need something more elaborate.

Ableton Live 8 is my weapon of choice here, but most of the DAWs will do timestretch.  You can also get standalone timestretch apps, and there are also VST and AU filters that will do the same.  It's a fairly extensive list, just Google "audio timestretch" for some leads.

Answer (score 2):

You can use different media players like Windows Media Player, [Media Player HomeCinema](http://mpc-hc.sourceforge.net/), or [VLC](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/) that have speed controls.

Comment: Oh nice. Does VLC play sound though? Is there any speed control with Winamp? I tried a speed control plugin but it crashes WinAmp. :( And Windows Media Player doesn't allow fine-tuning of speed

Comment: @InquilineKea VLC will play audio. As for WinAmp I'm not sure about that as I don't use WinAmp. And IIRC in Windows Media Player its under one of the advanced controls.

Comment: Oh okay I see - thanks. I'll try it right now.